# Program lets the user enter numbers until they enter zero and then prints total, number of inputs, and average

Tags: java, loops

I am able to get the program to ask for numbers until zero is entered and when zero is entered, the program displays total, entries, and avg. but the values given are incorrect.

Here is my code:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Question14 {

    public static void main (String [] args){
        double number = 0;
        double average = 0;
        int count = 0;
        double sum = 0;

        System.out.print("enter a number: ");

        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        number = sc.nextInt();

        while (number > 0){
            System.out.print("enter a number: ");
            number = sc.nextInt();
            count++;
            sum += number;
            average = sum/count;
        }

        if (number == 0){
            System.out.println("total: " + sum);
            System.out.println("number of entries: " + count);
            System.out.println("average: " + average);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You skip the first number - the one read before the loop. Also, there is no need to calc average until after the loop.

Comment: You seem to be throwing away the first number entered.  You don't start adding up and counting until they've entered the second number.

Comment: `number > 0` does not mean until `0` is entered.  The correct way would be `number != 0`, or else any negative values will also exit the loop.

Answer (score -1):

Just go for this:

```
    int input = 0, sum = 0, i = 0;

    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    do {
        System.out.println("Enter a number: ");
        input = sc.nextInt();
        sum += input;
        i++;
    } while (input != 0);

    System.out.println("Sum: " + sum);
    System.out.println("Avg: " + (double) (sum/i));
```

Comment: If u want to print the number of numbers you entered as well u just need to print i

Comment: This rounds the average down.  Probably not what was wanted.

Comment: Also, it includes the final zero in the average, which was probably also not what was wanted.  So for example, if you want the average of `6` and `7`, this will display `4` (that is, `(6+7+0)/3`, rounded down).

Comment: Than you just modify the avg output to: "Avg: " + ((sum*1.0)/i); so you get a not rounded answer.